# export SQL statements from Oracle 11g database via command line

Tags: oracle, export

I'd like to export an Oracle 11g database as a series of SQL statements via the command line.  I'd like the functionality of SQL Developer (the process described here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10071/7660) but via the command line.

Note that the data must be in a flat file and not a binary format (as with imp/exp or impdp/expdb (Datapump)).

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this? There is no out-of-the-box way to do this from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by 'from the command line', but you can generate the DDL via the `dbms_metadata` package (see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8392/automatic-oracle-sql-developer-for-exporting-ddl) for example).

If you want the data as well then you'd then have to roll your own, unless you find a generic script somewhere on the web. Automating the script with dynamic SQL and the data disctionary is certainly possible - it's what SQL*Developer must do ultimtately - it will just need some work to get right, and to handle things like embedded quotes. No quick fix I'm afraid.